# Using .htaccess to redirect /vote to /vote.php?vote=1

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with my .htaccess file. So far, nothing seems to work. I have made a PHP file called vote.php that uses GET variables to redirect the user to the appropriate voting website. Now, I want the user to be able to type myurl.com/vote1 which will redirect them to myurl.com/vote.php?vote=1 and so on vor /vote2, /vote3, /vote4 and /vote5
All help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Tanner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^vote([0-9]+)/?$ /vote.php?vote=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

For URL Rewrite or MOD_RE-WRITE in php.
Please go through this link..;

[Mode_RwWrite Tutotial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/)

Hope this Helps,
Thanks

Comment: Pleases, Mark it as Answer if it helped you.

Comment: This is just a comment posted in answer section and you're expecting to be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ vote.php?vote=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

I think you will still need to configure routing if you are not done with that ;)

Comment: OP wants URI as `/vote1`, `/vote2` etc this won't work with that requirement.